# How to display a JLabel on top of another JLabel, with specified coordinate?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm working on a GUI for a Tic Tac Toe project, in which I want to get an image (the player's move) to show up when clicking the corresponding area. However, I can't figure out how to display a JLabel (the move) on top of another JLabel (the background).

I have searched and tried to use layeredpanes, but it just fails to show the entire frame when I run it. I am new to GUI, so I am not quite sure if I implemented it correctly.

`layer = new JLayeredPane();
        //set up the board as background
        String path = "sampleUrl"; 
        URL url = new URL(path);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
        bg4 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        layer.add(bg4, new Integer(-1));
        frame.add(layer);
        frame.pack();
        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseListener4());
        String xPath = "sampleUrl";
        URL xUrl = new URL(xPath);
        BufferedImage x = ImageIO.read(xUrl);
        icon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(x));
        layer.add(icon);`

It just shows up a window with minimum width and height, without displaying the background. Is there something wrong with this code, or any other ways for me to put a JLabel on top of another JLabel?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you use an IDE? It is often useful for beginners to create Forms in an easy way. The generated code gives you useful hints to do it by hand in another case.
If your current problem (window does not show at all) is solved, you can go on with your label task.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one label object into another, as JLabel is a container. Try something like this.

```
JLabel parentLabel = new JLabel("Parent");
JLabel childLabel = new JLabel("Child");
parentLabel.add(childLabel );
```

Comment: I tried, but when I run it, it does not show the childLabel for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to read about javafx if you are new in GUI.you can merge nodes in any way you need.you can put labels on each other using stackpane,and display them top and down of each other using gridpane very easily.
more information on:
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! It seems like it is really different from traditional coding. Is it possible to get the java code after I finished?

Comment: if you have a basic information about fxml this might help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057935/add-a-label-on-top-of-an-imageview-that-is-on-a-tilepane